# Jest: How can I get the arguments called in jest mock function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I am learning manual mocking with jest mocks, now I would like to get arguments called in jest mock function, here is my solution.

```
 expect(mockLogin).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      {
        "email": "test@mail.com", 
        "password": "password", 
        "remember_me": false
       }
    );
```

Now when I run `npm test` I get the following results.
[image]

The problem I can't figure out how to add `"auth/login"` path in my expected results, I tried the following, but unfortunately it's not working.

```
   expect(mockLogin).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/auth/login", {
        "email": "test@mail.com", 
        "password": "password", 
        "remember_me": false
       });
```

What do I need to do to add `auth/login` to my expected results?

Comment: Could you post the code of your test? And maybe additionally the code you're testing.

Answer (score 3):

There must be something else going on.

Here is a simple example that works:

```js
describe('example', () => {
    test('mock called with', () => {
        const mock = jest.fn();
        const signin = {
            "email": "test@mail.com",
            "password": "password",
            "remember_me": false
        };
        mock('/auth/login', signin);

        expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/auth/login', {
            "email": "test@mail.com",
            "password": "password",
            "remember_me": false
           });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [mockFn.mock.calls](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls)

```
expect(mockLogin.mocks.call[0][0]).toEqual("/auth/login");
expect(mockLogin.mocks.call[0][1]).toEqual({
  "email": "test@mail.com", 
  "password": "password", 
  "remember_me": false
});
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: Are you mocking this function?

Comment: which function ??? here is mocked api https://ibb.co/61sX5K5

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(mockLogin).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/auth/login', {
  "email": "test@mail.com",
  "password": "password", 
  "remember_me": false
}]);
```

`toHaveBeenCalledWith` would expect array of arguments.